# Usage of REGEXP_SIMILAR in Teradata

Tags: sql, regex, teradata

I'm working on Teradata and trying to use REGEXP_SIMILAR function.

```
 *** Teradata Database Release is 14.10.03.10                   
 *** Teradata Database Version is 14.10.03.06
```

Here's my sample data.

```
create table test_table(
    test_col varchar(20)
);

insert into test_table values('lorem');
insert into test_table values('984kd');
insert into test_table values('ier7j');
insert into test_table values('34535');
insert into test_table values('lore9');
insert into test_table values(' 09sd');
```

I want to see the records which start with a number.

```
select test_col, regexp_similar(test_col, '^\d+','i')
from test_table;

test_col              regexp_similar(test_col,'^\d+','i')
--------------------  -----------------------------------
lore9                                                   0
lorem                                                   0
 09sd                                                   0
ier7j                                                   0
984kd                                                   0
34535                                                   1
```

But, the above query shows a match only for '34535' row and not for '984kd'. Seems like `^` character(also `$`) don't have the desired effect.

Isn't REGEXP_SIMILAR similar to REGEXP_LIKE of Oracle?

Can someone explain why is this happening and how to solve this.

Comment: Yes, that works. But ^ and $ are not needed at all? I find it strange after using REGEXP_LIKE in Oracle.

Comment: `^` and `$` are for a complete match.You dont need `$` but you defineitly need `^` so that you match a line starting with integer.

Answer (score 1):

```
^\d+.*
```

Try this.This will give the result.

Comment: Yes, this works. It will work even without `^`. Which means ^ and $ are redundant in REGEXP_SIMILAR, and pattern is compared with the entire string and not in parts.